# How to transfer View but will not close the View data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Sorry, my question is not clean. i want to do the Iphone application A view go to B view, but when i click the button go B View the A View data will remove.
So i would like to know if i want to B View go back A View , the A View can keep the data?

for example : A View doing some job, but i click the button go B View. this time i go back A 
View, the A View can still doing. This task is possible? not use navigation bar and tar bar only use button to transfer.

Thank you some one help.

i mean view controller thank you very much

Comment: Are you sure you mean views and not view controllers?  These are very different things and the answer depends on which one you are talking about.

Comment: What you mean to "transfer"? You can use NavigationController for changing views without losing its data.

Comment: How you are moving in between views, pushViewController, presentModal, Add subview, etc - which method you are using?
Or please place the code to clarify your question.

Comment: thank you some one help i mean view controllers~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for example : A View doing some job, but i click the button go B View. this time i go back A View, the A View can still doing. This task is possible? not use navigation bar and tar bar only use button to transfer.

As I understand you need launch some background task in **view controller** A and go to **view controller** B?
If I right you can do it with these steps:

1. Launch task that you need to do in background. You can do it by `performSelectorInBackground:@sel` or another way. Also you need somehow indicate when background task is done.
2. Show view controller B by `presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated`. Your background task in view controller A continue executing.
3. In view controller B make button which will work as "back" button. Add action to button and in this action do [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
4. When you return to view controller A, you can see your background task still executing (or already done)

Comment: thank you very much, so if i have C View controller and  D View controller can i use these steps?

Comment: example: A --> B --> C --> D --> A 
A viewController can keep in background?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you just want to return to previous view. This is easy but I also didn't know and made segue circle.

You have to write codes, but very short.

You must add UIViewController file and set to the second view as below (This is a little difficult I think):

[image: SetViewController]

Then you must just add below codes:

```
- (IBAction)back:(id)sender {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I made a sample project here:https://github.com/weed/p120801_SegueSampleProject

You can download and just run it.

I wish my advice is help for you.

Comment: if i have A , B, C, D View can i use this?